# Evaluation of function argument inside a nested requirement

Tags: c++, c++20

Can a function argument appear as an evaluated operand within the constraint-expression of a nested requirement? And, are there different rules when the placeholder type of the function argument is of a *structural type*? Clang seems to rejects the following code, while GCC and MSVC accept it:

```
struct s { static constexpr auto b = true; };

constexpr auto f(auto a)
{ return requires { requires a; }; }

template<auto A>
constexpr auto g()
{ return requires { requires A.b; }; }

constexpr auto h(auto a)
{ return requires { requires a.b; }; }

static_assert(f(true));  // all fail
static_assert(g<s{}>()); // all ok
static_assert(h(s{}));   // fails on clang
```

The standard describes that local parameters introduced by a requires-expression have no linkage, storage, or lifetime ([[expr.prim.req.general]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.req.general#4.sentence-4)). And so, they should only appear as an unevaluated operand within a constraint-expression of a nested requirement ([[expr.prim.req.nested]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.req.nested#2)). But does that also apply to function arguments that are local to an encompassing function scope?

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/obszj48vo)

Comment: But `a` isn't a template parameter.

Comment: @PasserBy Yeah, you're right. Maybe the observed discrepancy is in some way related to the overlap between function arguments with placeholder types and local parameters of a requires-expression.